TypeScript: why check of type object[] fails if array contains an empty object variable?
Why the check for type object[] fails, if the array contains a variable containing an empty object like this:
let emptyObject = {};
let objectArray : object[] = [emptyObject, true, 1]; // no compile error, but should throw error

Playground link
This doesn't show any error or warning, but it should, since true and 1 shouldn't be possible in an array with type object[].
If I use an empty object literal {} directly or a non-empty object, everything works as expected:
let objectArray2 : object[] = [{}, true, 1]; // as excpected: type 'boolean' is not assignable to 'object'
let nonEmptyObject = {a: 1};
let objectArray3 : object[] = [nonEmptyObject, true, 1]; // as expected: type 'boolean' is not assignable to 'object'

Playground link
Is this a bug of TypeScript, or am I missing something?
I'm using TypeScript version 5.4.5.

Interestingly, let emptyObject : object = {}; makes the typecheck fail, while let emptyObject : {} = {}; does not.

Also, it does not seem to matter if emptyObject is the first element or not.

It's a TS design decision, not a bug. The type {} includes primitives, the object type does not. But while TS knows that the value {} value is not a primitive, the type that it gets is just {} which might be a primitive. Technically then the compiler should complain if you assign the {} type to object, which would make things consistent but very very annoying. This GitHub comment explains why they allow it. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?

What's unclear to me is why the value {} automatically gets the type {} and not object (which would make much more sense)?

@klues - LOL, that's what I said. :-)

The problem doesn't come up in practice enough for it to be worth implementing. Maybe every object literal should get a type with object in it (so {length: 1} would be of type {length: number} & object instead of just {length: number}, as the issue isn't unique to the empty object) but it would add complexity to the language that would have to pay for itself in improvements people care about without breaking too much existing code. You're welcome to make such a suggestion in GitHub, but I wouldn't be optimistic about it. So, shall I write up an answer or is something still missing?

@jcalz - What do you mean by "...as the issue isn't unique to the empty object..."? Is {length: 1} not necessarily an object type? I tried assigning a single-character string to {length: 1} but TypeScript didn't like it (which came as a big relief :-) ).

TS doesn't know that a single-character string has {length: 1} but it does know that every string is a {length: number} as shown here. This is the intentional behavior of TS, which is mentioned in the aforementioned github comment and the comment linked within. string is assignable to String which is assignable to any widening of it, including {length: number}.

@jcalz - Thanks, I did wonder if coercion was the reason. (I should have thought to try {length: number}).

after all this is the thing I still don't understand. @t-j-crowder: I know it was your comment, but I didn't know how to refer to it (and how do I mention your username)?!

@klues - It's explained in the github comment jcalz posted above. Basically, it's for backward compatibility with code written before object was added in TS v2.2. (You can refer to comments using the link in the time at the very end of the comment. You mentioned my username correctly, using @. You can only do that when A) The person has previously interacted with the post, and B) They aren't the author of the post [because SO has a dumb policy about that].)

A quick Google search to this article

The empty object type - {} - doesn't behave how you expect in TypeScript.


Instead of representing an empty object, it represents any value except null and undefined.

Which means type {} is effectively any minus undefined and null, you can expect it behave similar to any when null and undefined aren't in the equation, i.e. opt-out type checking.
When you have some elements in an array opted out type checking, the whole array is opted out.
let emptyObject = {}; effectively declared emptyObject as type {}, while the empty object inside [{}, true, 1] has not yet asserted a type, so it get a chance follow the type of the array.
If you write [{} as {}, true, 1];, the error will get removed, same effect as [{} as any, true, 1];
In reverse, if you write let emptyObject : object = {};, this narrow the type of the empty object from type {} to type object, and the error appear.

OK, thanks. Is there any official documentation about the empty object type? Appears strange tome, that it has such a special meaning, but no offical docs for it.

I think it is a natural result of interpretation. Typescript is separated in type space and runtime space. The { } notation in type space means an interface, not an runtime object. Think about when you write let a: {a:number} = {a:1}, {a:number} is a type, not an object. Interface is more or less equivalent to type, anything even primitives have a type. number is a type, string is a type. Empty interface { } means a type that has no requirements on its properties and methods. Therefore any type can fit in.

I once wrote an answer on that question here with playground proof (please ignore the accepted answer because its incorrect) and there's an explanation in the FAQ on Github as well.

Thanks @RickyMo, makes sense. However I still don't get it why the empty object literal {} seems to get inferred to the type {} (any, but not empty), and not to type object - also see the comments of the other answer.

This is due to TypeScript's Best Common Type inference of the array.
When you say
let emptyObject = {};
let objectArray: object[] = [emptyObject, true, 1];

the array is actually inferred with type {}[]. And {}[] is assignable to object[]. So there's no compiler error.
You can change the type inference by using a const-assertion like so:
let emptyObject = {};
let objectArray: object[] = [emptyObject, true, 1] as const; 
//                                        ~~~~  ~
// ... is not assignable to type 'object'.

That way the array will be inferred as a tuple with type readonly [{}, true, 1] which is clearly not assignable to object[].
TypeScript Playground

OK, thanks, but let array = [{}, true, 1]; is also inferred to type {}[], so why let objectArray2 : object[] = [{}, true, 1]; gives an error and let objectArray : object[] = [emptyObject, true, 1] not?

What really surprises me here is that the type of an empty object literal is inferred as {}, not object or something similar. The {} type, as you said, doesn't represent an object with no properties, it represents any type other than nullish ones. To me, that means that it shouldn't be inferred as the type of...well...anything, really.

Thinking more of this, I don't understand why type {}[] is assignable to object[]. Type {} also fits for literals like true, while object doesn't. So {} allows more types and it makes no sense that it's assignable to object. It would only make sense, if {} would be a subtype of object.

Honestly, I have no idea why that is the case. The general subtype compatability rules do not seem to apply here. But matter of fact: The type {} is assignable to type object and vice versa.

OK, @jcalz already explained it in this comment. So maybe you should add this explanation to your answer and also a short explanation what the {} type is. I think then we would finally have an answer that should clarify everything.

@klues I can surely edit my answer accordingly and include jcalz's explanation if he's okay with that but jcalz asked if he should write up an answer multiple times. So, I think it's better if he writes up his own thoughts than me paraphrasing.

OK, @jcalz: I'm ok with both, as you like.
